# What are the best practices to separate data from users

Tags: java, sql, architecture

For a customer we where developing a big application that where open to all users if you will, meaning, all users could see each others data.

Now suddenly the customer is saying that they want only users belonging to the same organization to be able to view each others data.

So we came up with this data model: 
[image: user's organization]

So now the question is: How is it best to separate the data?

This is the only alternative I see:

- SQL JOIN on ALL relevant tables (All tables that have data should no always join on Organization)
  -- All queries should now add an extra join to Organization, and if the join doesn't exists, we need to create a new foreign key.

But I feel an extra join (We have around 20 tables that needs extra join) is quite costly.

I hope there are some other best practices or solutions we can consider.

PS: This is a Web application developed using Java/JSF/Seam (but I don't know if that is relevant)

**UPDATE**

I want to clarify something. My consurn is not security but performance. We have added the foreign key to organization to all relevant tables that has shared data, and we are using user's logged in organization to filter the data.

All I want to know is if this is a good architectural solution (inner join) or if we should do something else (ie: Load all shared data, and filter in memory instead of sql join).

Comment: But if it's all the same company split into separate organisations under the hood, and a user has a role at one organisation as well as a role at the other (as they work in two offices for example). This model wouldn't work for this, is this a possibility? I hope I've not miss understood the question :-)

Comment: No this is not a possibility. A user can only be part of one organization, and there is no "company". The Organization is just a name. It is really more demographic. So could actually be Country (makes more sense)

Answer (score 4):

You really have to understand the difference between the persistency layer and the application layer.

It doesn't matter how you define your database tables, as anyone with database access *will* have access to all the users data. What **does** matter is how you define the behavior in your application.

Changing the database design should only be done for performance reasons, **not** for security - which should be handled in the application.

Comment: To add further, you may want to take a look at Spring Security http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/index.html. It allows you to declaratively define your application security requirements.

Comment: Maybe I didn't make my self clear, but my concern is not security but only performance. 
I know performing a join is costly, maybe there is a better way?

Comment: Why did you decide a join is necessary? Is there no other way to design the query?

Comment: We did a join because thats the only way I knew how I could separate the data. The Organization table had to be hooked to all the other tables where data was shared.

Answer (score 1):

I would reckon that the best pattern would be to only expose the user details through the web application, so at that point its a case of restricting the data exposed to each user.  This will allow you to build in the required security inside the application.

Alternatively if you are allowing direct database access then you will need to create a login/user (depends on database used) for each organization or user and then restrict the access of these login/user entities to parameterized stored procedures rather than the base tables.  This will push security back onto the database, which is riskier but still do-able.

As to meta changes to support the organization column, parameterizing the stored procedures will be fairly trivial:

```
select @organizationId = organizationId from User where User.id = @currentUserId

select * from User where organizationId = @organizationId
```

(depending on the sql flavour you will need to enclose some entities eg ``User, [User] etc)

Comment: So how is this different from creating an extra join in the sql? Will this perform faster than the join?

Comment: @Shervin If you are doing a recursive join it will self-join back to the User table for as many rows as there are in the query - but pushing the lookup to organizationId into a scalar query and then using that constant value will perform the same task faster than if there are thousands of self-joins.

Comment: If there are only a handful of rows then this technique may not be faster (although it will never be slow as long as organizationId and userId are keys).

Comment: What do you mean recursive join? One inner join is not recursive?

Comment: @Shervin I was assuming you would be linking back to the User table (from the User table) to see which other Users were in the same organization as the current user (does that make sense?).  That would be recursive.

Comment: Aah yes no that is not one I do. What we have done is hook the Organization directly (as foreign key) against all the relevant tables. Seemed like the easiest solutions, but it doesnt feel right. Thats why I wanted to know of a better solution

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason that Organization has to be 'joined' at all.

If your 'data' tables all have OrganizationID columns, then you can lookup the 'organizationID' from the user and then add this as a condition to the join.

EX:

```
select @OrganizationId = organizationId from User where User.id = @currentUserId
select * from datatable a ....  where .... AND a.organizationID = @organizationID
```

See; no join.

With respect to performance, there are different types of joins, and SQLServer allows you to hint at the type of join.  So in some cases, a merge join is the best, whereas in something like this scenario, a loop join would be the best.  Not sure if these choices are available in MySQL.

With respect to *all* of your tables needing a join, or condition (see above), there is a logical answer, and an implementation answer.  The implementation answer depends on your indexing.  If you can limit the dataset the most by adding that condition, then you will benefit.  But if the join with the other table that has already been filtered does a better job at reducing rows, then the condition will be worthless (or worst case, it will use the wrong index).  Assuming you have indexes on your join and condition columns.

Logically, only data that isn't *fully* dependent on a table that is filtered by organizationID needs that extra condition.  If you have a car table, and carparts table, then you only have to filter the car table.  Unless for some reason you don't need to join with the car table for some joins, in which case you will need that organizationID on the parts table too.